# Sort null values last with DataTables in R

Tags: r, datatables, dt, flexdashboard

I am currently using a `datatable` in an `rmarkdown` document to create a `flexdashboard`. I have a numeric column with NA's in it.  When I click to sort the column in descending order it puts the largest value first and the NA/null values last.  When I sort in ascending order it puts the NA/null values first and then the numeric values.  Is there a way to sort the null value last when sorting in ascending order?  It looks like `DataTables` might have a [plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/absolute) for this very issue but I see it is [not supported](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/plugins.html) by the R DataTables version. I'm looking to be able to sort the numeric columns the same way RStudio does with a table when you view it.

Here is a reproducible example of the functionality I am looking for:

```
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)


Table.with.null <- tibble(Category=c("A","B","C","D"),
                          Numeric=seq(1,4),
                          Numeric.null=c(1,2,3,NA))

datatable(Table.with.null,rownames=FALSE)
```

When I sort the `Numeric.null` column in *ascending* order the table should look like this:

```
Category  Numeric  Numeric.null
A         1        1
B         2        2
C         3        3
D         4        NA
```

Which it does.  When I sort `Numeric.null` column in *descending* order the table should look like this:

```
Category  Numeric  Numeric.null
C         3        3
B         2        2
A         1        1
D         4        NA
```

Comment: The funny thing I've noticed is that when rendering a table using `DT::renderDataTable` through a shiny app, which sends the output to `datatable`, this sort of sorting is already solved.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to provide sorting function using *callback* argument. The js function from the example doesn't work for me (I guess `value` argument should be supplied - it needs a bit of work), but here is example with my own sorting function.

Important note is that sorting column type should be changed to character just before calling `datatable` function. Also keep in mind that while `rownames` DT argument is set to `FALSE` columns have numbers `0,1,2,...`

```
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

temp <-mtcars
temp[1, "wt"] <- NA
temp[2, "wt"] <- NA

#OUTPUT - dtdata
DT::datatable({
  temp %>% mutate(wt = as.character(wt))
},
callback = JS("
  $.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['NumericOrBlank-asc'] = function(x,y) {
    var retVal;
        if( x === '' || $.isEmptyObject(x)) x = 1000;
    if( y === '' || $.isEmptyObject(y)) y = 1000;
    x = (x = parseFloat($.trim(x).replace(/,/g,''))) ? x : 0;
    y = (y = parseFloat($.trim(y).replace(/,/g,''))) ? y : 0;
    if (x==y) retVal= 0; 
    else retVal = (x>y) ? 1 : -1; 
    return retVal;
  };
  $.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['NumericOrBlank-desc'] = function(y,x) {
  var retVal;
  x = (x = parseFloat($.trim(x).replace(/,/g,''))) ? x : 0;
  y = (y = parseFloat($.trim(y).replace(/,/g,''))) ? y : 0;
  if (x==y) retVal= 0; 
  else retVal = (x>y) ? 1 : -1; 
  return retVal;
  };
  "),
options = list(
  autoWidth = TRUE,
  aoColumnDefs = list(list(width = '100px', bSortable = TRUE, sType = 
'NumericOrBlank', targets = c(5)))
), rownames = FALSE)
```